# VScode jupyternotbook continues to try a lot of commands when it connects to the remote jupyter server Whenever Kernels interrupted

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

```
[W 19:10:36.246 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1677957034769 (211.209.3.124) 0.900000ms referer=None
[W 19:10:43.866 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 19:10:43.866 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1677957042389 (211.209.3.124) 1.130000ms referer=None
[W 19:10:45.758 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 19:10:45.758 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1677957044282 (211.209.3.124) 0.900000ms referer=None
[W 19:10:47.176 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 19:10:47.177 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1677957045701 (211.209.3.124) 0.900000ms referer=None
```

If I exit the kernel from the vscode jumper notebook, I can still receive these messages from the remote Jupiter server.

```
 registered and have sufficient resources
[I 21:20:52.727 NotebookApp] Kernel interrupted: 56e9a17c-cf4a-4d61-a44e-102cc896ded7
23/03/04 21:21:03 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
23/03/04 21:21:18 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
23/03/04 21:21:33 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Even if i shut down the kernel , yarn will continue to work

and sometimes do the same Spark job several times.

I feel like the local jupyter notebook is constantly giving orders regardless of me.

Local jupyternotebook in vscode  keep trying to get into the remote jupyter server, and  keep running the code that I ran only once

I'm sure there's no problem with the jumper server.
The problem is in the vscode jupyter notebook.
Because remote access works very well in the Chrome browser.

I reinstalled extension and deleted the vscode cache and server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and found out that if I just restart both VSCode and the server, it works. I also discovered that if I run the server from outside VSCode, it works just fine.

After some digging, I realized VSCode (or the Notebook plug-in) automatically sets pyenv to its preferred Python. So if I just do a `pyenv use` with the version that has everything correct before starting, it works.

Comment: I tried this and it worked: reopened VSCode, started the jupyter notebook server from an external terminal instead of the terminal within VSCode. I also had to open an ssh tunnel to the report host to export the port on localhost. This ssh command could be run from within a VSCode terminal and that did not cause a problem.